# Adobe Reader -"This file could not be accessed Check the location or the network and try again."

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, adobe-reader

Hey all and Merry Christmas. I have some issues with my Nexus 5 and its behavior regarding .pdf files within Chrome. You know all that after downloading any pdf file from the Web the next step is opening automatically with any pdf reader that is set by default(eg. Adobe Reader in my case latest version). This worked without any problems till some weeks ago, when phone stumbled on the error from the Title. I can open manually the .pdf files after this failed process by navigating through the source but it kinda bugs me why it is not working anymore as it should. 
Tried the following but it was in avail: Master/Hard reset, uninstalling all updates of both apps(Chrome and Adobe) though Chrome has nothing to do with it i guess and installing just Adobe.

P.S: This is weird also > Even with Drive PDF Viewer it doesn't open automatically after download. It just minimizes after completion and again i must navigate to the download folder and open it manually.

P.S.2: On Nexus 6P this issue is non-existent, I tested it and the process works fine.

Does anyone has any idea what's happening?

Android Version: 6.0.1 Marshmallow, not rooted.

L.T: To shadow this issue if it can't be fixed can i in some way disable automatic opening after downloading .pdf files?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? Same issue here.

Comment: Nop. I have other issues with it beside that, maybe they are related like, no sim card from time to time, reset loops but this is from the power button and it can be fixed via cleaning. Perhaps it's time to get a new phone because he is kinda old, 2 years almost i think + accidentaly droped several times. Anyway do you have these problems too? The last two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe has finally fixed this issue through an update.